# SonarQube - Delete and recreate SonarQube Project with same name

Tags: sonarqube

I want to delete and recreate a SonarQube project. Can i re-use same name? After deleting the project can I immediately request for new SonarQube project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. SonarQube will delete the project from the database. Requesting a scan of a project with the same identifier will create a project using the same key (sonar identifier) since SonarQube no longer knows about the deleted project.